# What 2 and 4 decimal number has the largest difference against its double IEEE754 representation?

Tags: fractions, decimal-expansion

We know that fractional numbers that are powers of 2 like 0.25 (2^-2) or 0.0625 (2^-4) can be represented exactly in a floating point or double type variable.

Any fractional number that is also an exact sum of a power of 2 can also be exactly represented.

However, 0.01 cannot be exactly represented. It will be 0.009999999999999787 when stored as a double type value (binary64).

So, I am wondering whether there is a value or values that will present with the largest discrepancy.

Comment: In absolute value or relative?

Comment: Are you looking for absolute or relative differences?

Comment: There are only 100 2-decimal numbers, and only 10,000 4-decimal numbers, so why not try them all to see which one (or, which ones) has the largest difference?

Comment: absolute value difference would be good.

Comment: Smallest numbers with maximum absolute error: `0.56  -> 5.32907051820075120E-0017` and  `0.5126  ->  5.54223333892878120E-0017`

Comment: Thanks Gammatester. I was trying to figure out python code to work it out, but couldn't get very far.